# "any of them" vs "either of them"

Tags: determiners, quantifiers, partitives

Aren't "any" and "either" both correct in no.89?

> 89. We looked at two hotels on the internet and ……… of them would be great for a holiday.
>     (a) all   (b) every   (c) either   (d) any

[image: questions 87-89]

and in no.144 is it *none* or *neither* and why?

> 144. I searched and searched but ……of the shops sold that particular brand of clothing.
>      (a) neither (b) all  (c) none  (d) some

[image: questions 144-146]

Comment: 144. "Neither" suggests there were only two shops, but "I searched and searched" suggests there were many. So the answer is c) none.

Comment: 89. Again, "any" suggests there were more than two hotels, but "either" distinguishes between two. So c) either.

Comment: Please write a more specific title next time, asking about questions 89 and 144 means nothing to those browsing the page.

Answer (score 1):

No. 89. "either" is used for two objects.  "any" is used for more than two.

No. 144. If you searched two shops it would be "neither" if you searched many shops it would be "none".

Comment: i don't know if  i am replying to you miss's chasly i am new at this forum but anyways thanks for your answer that's what i thought but how in no.144 can i know the number of the shops is it more than two because it means that he/she searched alot?

Comment: You can't know for certain the number of shops, but "none" is a better bet, especially given the context of "searched and searched".